# How to search for projects in GitHub written in more than 1 language?

Tags: github-api

I want to extract projects from GitHub using qualifiers as filters and according to https://github.com/search/advanced, it seems like it is not possible to search for projects written in more than 1 languege. For example, I want to retrieve projects whose main language are java, but has a front-end written in html, javascript, and the frameworks bootstrap, jquery, etc, so the language filter should allow an "and" in the selection. Is there a good way to realize this search ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not possible using search. As a workaround, you might consider fetching the list of projects for a specific language using search, and then fetch the other languages using a different API endpoint:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-languages

Once you have that -- you can filter on your end based on the full list of languages.

Comment: isn't it the same as redoing the operation by selecting other languages in github searh ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean -- redo how and which operation? Happy to answer that question if you could be more clear and precise.

Comment: redo the search using https://github.com/search/advanced and selecting another language, one by one.

Comment: @Digao I still don't understand how that would work. But I do think that automating this via the API will make the process easier, and using the https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-languages API endpoint is a bit better since it has a better rate limit than search -- search has a lower API/UI rate limit since searches are expensive to compute.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible now(Dec, 2020) to search for repositories written in multiple languages, like searching repos in js or ts.

- option 1: use github search input ui

  - just type `angular language:javascript language:typescript` in the input and hit enter to search
- option 2: use github search api

  - https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=angular+language:javascript+language:typescript&per_page=5&page=1

Comment: Note that that this searches for repos with *either* language, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the github API option, they now provide the [gh](https://github.com/cli/cli) CLI tool.

```sh
gh api -X GET search/repositories \
  -f q='language:shell language:javascript' \
  -f sort=stars \
  --jq '.items[] | { full_name, stargazers_count, language, description }'
```

though I think the languages are ORed, not ANDed.